# GCM chrome 50 send multiple push notifications

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In Chrome version below 50  we had the ability to send messages in batch of 1,000 on a single request. With the advent of encryption in the new version of Chrome (50+) has become necessary to make a separate request for each message. Is it possible in Chrome version 50 to send messages in batch?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [HTTP messaging using the JSON format](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) and a [POST request](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream).

> *registration_ids* - This parameter specifies a list of devices
>   (registration tokens, or IDs) receiving a multicast message. It must
>   contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration tokens.
>
> Use this parameter only for multicast messaging, not for single
>   recipients. Multicast messages (sending to more than 1 registration
>   tokens) are allowed using HTTP JSON format only.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to encrypt  message for every chrome50  customer, encryption keys are indicated in the request header:  Encryption: salt=<SALT>,  Crypto-Key: dh=<PUBLICKEY>,   Content-Encoding: aesgcm.  So this way is not worked more